# May I ask questions in German?

Tags: discussion, support, language, asking-questions

As I read in the [Tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour), this site is not only dedicated to translation from or into German, but also to *discussing* the *finer points of the language*.

Is it okay if German native speakers asks questions in German?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did not mention this explicitely in the tour but if you scrolled further down you see a link to our [help center](https://german.stackexchange.com/help). There you can read in the "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" section:

> Questions in both, English and German are welcome but note that posts on Meta should always be in English.

So yes, asking and answering in both German, and English is welcome here. Look around and you will see many questions and answers in German. We have however a loose policy to try to answer a question in the language it was written.

Also see:

[What language should the questions be written in?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-language-should-the-questions-be-written-in)
[What language is preferrable for answers to questions written in German?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/772/what-language-is-preferrable-for-answers-to-questions-written-in-german)

Comment: As I see the both questions you quoted, do I understand this right that this is also true here on the German Language meta?

Comment: No, all Meta posts need to be in English: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/325/please-use-english-on-the-meta-site

Comment: Okay, fine, accepted. Would it be possible to add these informations to the tour, or is there an FAQ?

Comment: The FAQ is our **Help Center** which can be reached with a link at the bottom oof the tour, or on any SE site from the "Help" menu in the top bar.

Comment: @Wolf: Regarding the placement of that particular piece of information, see also [Should and can we make more clear to newcomers that we are bilingual?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/640/2594)

Comment: Added "bilingual" to the tour description - may it help ;)

Comment: You didn't recognize it is a duplicate?