# Was machen wir mit den ganzen "Ist das richtig?" Fragen?

Tags: discussion

Leider kommen zunehmend Fragen mit völlig nutzlosen Titeln wie zum Beispiel:

> - [Ist dieser Satz richtig?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49014/ist-dieser-satz-richtig)
> - [Help translate a clue for a novel](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48991/help-translate-a-clue-for-a-novel)
> - [Welcher Satz ist grammatisch richtig? Oder beide sind falsch? "in Relativsatz"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48972/welcher-satz-ist-grammatisch-richtig-oder-beide-sind-falsch-in-relativsatz)
> - [Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen "ist nicht zu verkaufen", "lässt sich nicht verkaufen" und "ist unverkäuflich"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48941/wo-liegt-der-unterschied-zwischen-diesen-s%c3%a4tzen)
> - [Syntax analysis for a complicated sentence](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48936/syntax-analysis-for-a-complicated-sentence)
> - [Ein Buch über Bitcoin](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48906/ein-buch-%c3%bcber-bitcoin)

Weil diese Titel wichtig sind, damit wir, oder Suchmaschinen die Fragen wiederfinden, sollten wir darauf achten, dass sie den Inhalt der Frage widerspiegeln.

Was können oder sollen wir tun, damit diese Fragen nicht tage- oder wochenlang auf unserer Eingangsseite sitzen? Wie können wir es neuen Usern schmackhaft machen, aussagekräftige Titel zu wählen?

Comment: Dieses Fragen sind sehr lokalisiert, so dass ist nicht gut Fragen.

Answer (score 11):

1. Wenn möglich, also relativ eindeutig und schnell umzuformulieren: hemmungslose aber hilfreiche edits. Da es meist Newbies als Fragesteller sind, wäre ein aussagekräftiger edit-comment wünschenswert, und/oder ein regulärer Kommentar.

   Bei ehemals "wo-liegt-der-unterschied-zwischen-diesen-sätzen?" zu [Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen "ist nicht zu verkaufen", "lässt sich nicht verkaufen" und "ist unverkäuflich"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48941/wo-liegt-der-unterschied-zwischen-diesen-s%C3%A4tzen) schien mir das einfach und angebracht. Titel sollten spezifisch sein.
2. Wenn diese 'friendly edit'-Methode nicht anwendbar zu sein scheint: Kommentar mit Bitte um Klarstellung drunterstellen. Hoffen auf Kooperation des Fragestellers.
3. Wenn es wenig Hoffnung zu geben scheint: Kommentar plus vote-to-put-on-hold (Vote-to-Close).

Einige Fragen sind unrettbar.

---

Bei den meisten Beispielen in der Frage oben scheint dies auch der Fall zu sein. “Ist das richtig?”-Fragen scheinen nahe Verwandte der off-topic-Fragen zu sein.

Answer (score 1):

wenn es nicht erwünscht oder unangebracht erscheint, eine Frage mit: **ist es richtig** zu beginnen, oder mit **was heisst,** oder **was bedeutet**, könnte bei solchen  Fragen eine "Warnung"  aufleuchten, mit dem Hinweis, dass diese Frage zu allgemein gestellt ist oder den Abgleich mit anderen Fragen erschwert.

Comment: Es geht mir nicht um die Frage an sich (das haben wir schon oft diskutiert), sondern um den nichtssagenden **Titel** einer solchen Frage. Das ist fast schon so, als würde man hier jeden Beitrag mit "Ich will eine Antwort" betiteln.

Comment: alles klar!
Takkat, ich habe gerade den sehr wertvollen Verhaltenscodex gecheckt.Wo finde ich den Hinweis, in der Sprache des Fragestellers zu antworten? 
Ich möchte diese freundlich Absicht in Frage stellen und begründen, falls nötig.

Comment: Du meinst sicher dies: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/should-the-language-of-an-answer-match-the-language-used-in-the-question, aber es gibt noch ein [paar andere Beiträge zum Thema](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language?sort=votes&pageSize=50https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language?sort=votes&pageSize=50)